# Discord.py creates error by reactions. How do I fix?

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I have a problem with the discord.py Python library. I'm getting an error, every time someone reacts to messages.

Python do not show me, where the error comes from, but I think it's an error in the discord.py.
Last week the code worked but now its not working anymore. I'm becoming a headache about it. Can someone help my please?

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from emojis import emojis
import msg
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
import json
from uuid import uuid4

shop_channels = []
orders = {}
cmd_prefix = "dsb!"


def check_perms(user):
    for role in user.roles:
        if role.name == "":
            return True

    return False


def check_command(message, command):
    if message.startswith(cmd_prefix + command):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def save_settings():
    settings = {}
    settings["shop_channels"] = shop_channels
    settings["orders"] = orders
    with open("data.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(settings, file)


def load_settings():
    global shop_channels
    global orders

    with open("data.json") as file:
        settings = json.load(file)
        orders = settings["orders"]
        shop_channels = settings["shop_channels"]
        print(shop_channels)


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.msg = msg.Msg(True, "DiShoBo")

        print('-------')
        print('Logged in as')
        print('Username:', self.user.name)
        print('ID:', self.user.id)
        print('------', end="\n\n")
        load_settings()
        print("Settings loaded!\n\n")

    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
        print("hello")

        if shop_channels is None or reaction.message.channel.id not in shop_channels:
            return

        try:
            if reaction.emoji == emojis["shopping_cart"]:
                order_id = uuid4()

                item = reaction.message.content.partition('\n')[0]
                amount = reaction.message.content.partition('\n')[2]
                self.msg.debug("Got new order from user {0} for Item: {1}! OrderID: {2}".format(
                    user, item, order_id))
                if user.dm_channel == None:
                    await user.create_dm()
                message = await user.dm_channel.send("You ({2}) added the Item: '{0}' for {1} to your shopping cart!\nClick on :white_check_mark: to finish your order then go back to Angels 2B2T shop, or if you want to keep shopping, just go back to the shop and add more items.\nIf you want to clear your shopping cart, click the {3} below.\n\nYour OrderID is: {4}".format(item, amount, user.mention, emojis["cross_mark"], order_id))
                # await message.add_reaction(emojis["check_mark_box"])
                # await message.add_reaction(emojis["cross_mark"])

                if not message.author in orders:
                    orders.update(
                        {message.author: {"user": message.author, "ID": order_id, "items": []}})

                print(orders[message.author]["items"])
                orders[message.author]["items"].append({item, amount})
                print(orders[message.author]["items"])

            if not reaction.me and reaction.count > 1:
                await reaction.remove(user)
            else:
                await reaction.remove(user)
        except:
            pass


# * CONNECT
client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug on the hand of the `discord.py` library but was fixed in the update `1.3.2`.